# Prevent traefik from forwarding client IP

Tags: traefik

I use traefik as a reverse reverse proxy for my Docker host. Additionally, I want to set up a static proxy to an external server. This is my current configuration:

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

debug = false
logLevel = "ERROR"

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  compress = true
  [entryPoints.https.tls]

[api]

[docker]
domain = "myhost.com"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = false

[file]

[backends]

  [backends.otherhost]
    [backends.otherhost.servers]
      [backends.otherhost.servers.server0]
        url = "http://otherhost.com"

[frontends]

  [frontends.otherhost]
    entryPoints = ["http", "https"]
    backend = "otherhost"
    [frontends.otherhost.routes]
      [frontends.otherhost.routes.route0]
        rule = "Host:subdomain.myhost.com"
    [frontends.otherhost.headers.customRequestHeaders]
      X-Forwarded-For = "foo"
      X-Real-Ip = "foo"
```

Setting the headers to an empty string did nothing. With these settings, `X-Real-Ip` is `foo` but `X-Forwarded-For` becomes `foo, <my real IP>`. Can I prevent traefik from leaking the client IP to the external backend while still having it inside my Docker environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Traefik 2.x

What about using Middleware to override the `X-Forwarded-For` header. Documentation found [here](https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/middlewares/headers/).

```
[http.middlewares]
  [http.middlewares.testHeader.headers]
    [http.middlewares.testHeader.headers.customRequestHeaders]
        X-Forwarded-For = "foo"
    [http.middlewares.testHeader.headers.customResponseHeaders]
        X-Forwarded-For = "foo"
```

You can then apply specific middleware to your routers, like so:

```
[http.routers]
  [http.routers.router1]
    service = "myService"
    middlewares = ["testHeader"]
    rule = "Host(`example.com`)"

[http.middlewares]
  [http.middlewares.testHeader.headers]
    [http.middlewares.testHeader.headers.customRequestHeaders]
        X-Forwarded-For = "foo"
    [http.middlewares.testHeader.headers.customResponseHeaders]
        X-Forwarded-For = "foo"

[http.services]
  [http.services.service1]
    [http.services.service1.loadBalancer]

      [[http.services.service1.loadBalancer.servers]]
        url = "http://127.0.0.1:80"
```

References:

- Overview of Middleware - https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/middlewares/overview/
- Middwlare headers - https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/middlewares/headers/

Comment: It looks like it does what I want but I don't really understand middlewares. How do I apply it to a single frontend? Your example looks like it is scoped to the "http" endpoint.

Comment: Are you using Traefik 1.x? Within traefik 2.x you can apply middlewares to specific routers. See https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/middlewares/overview/ - I'll also update my answer.

Comment: I'm on 1.x but I could upgrade, even if 2.0.0 is not stable yet. Thanks for the hint, I only had a brief look at routers before. Also the docs state that `When you declare a middleware, it lives in its provider namespace.` so as long as I only have one frontend under `File` that could also work.